# Automating system using Selenium(Finding Image)

Tags: selenium

I am trying to find the field **"img"**

The following is the HTML code:

```
 <div id="mainFrameDiv" class="Frame">
    <div id="Header" class="Row">
    <nav class="navbar">
    <a href="servicesFindTravelers.cfm?prod=IBANK" class="menuOption">
    <img src="tempimages/DEMO_959_logo transparent background.png"/>
</a>
<div class="navmenu">
<div class="userinfoBar">
</nav>
</div>
```

The C# code that I am using is:

```
var h1Driver.Instance.FindElements(By.XPath("//a[@class='menuOption']/img[@src='tempimages/DEMO_959_logo transparent background.png']"));
            if (h1.Count > 0)
                return true;
            return false;
```

What I am trying to do is find the **Image**, but somehow it is unable to get the field.

Comment: The code is var h1 = Driver.Instance.FindElements(By.XPath("//a[@class='menuOption']/img[@src='tempimages/DEMO_959_logo transparent background.png']"));
                if (h1.Count > 0)
                    return true;
                return false;

Comment: Your xpath is correct. Seems like there are frames in your page and the problem could lie with you not switching to the correct frame. Could you post more of the HTML and your C# Code ?

Comment: Sorry, I misread the closing tag and relied on the indentation. The Xpath seems correct and I am able to find it with your original code. The thing I noticed is that your html code might not be correct. For ex: the `<div class="navmenu"><div class="userinfoBar">` are not closed, but then it is trying to close the `nav` tag. I would double check with the original html code first.